# Is there any way to detect step-like shape in time series data?

Tags: python, r, time-series

I want to detect any step shapes in time series as in the example plot. Only method that comes to my mind is taking differences of mean of first and second half of the series and compare it with the mean of differences. If mean of second half is greater than the mean of first half by some threshold (e.g mean + 3*sd), then I can say that there is a step-like shape in the data (hopefully). But it is not sensible to use midpoint of the serial since the step can be anywhere in the data.

```
apply(ds[1:6], 2, function(x){
    diffs = diff(x)
    l = floor(length(x) / 2)
    m1 = mean(x[1:l])
    m2 = mean(x[(l+1):length(x)])
    (m2-m1) > (mean(diffs) + 3*sd(diffs))
})
```

This method determines b also as a step shape. Any feasible solution using R or Python is acceptable.

Sample data:

```
> a = c(115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 115.9364, 132.6718, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154, 137.6154)
> plot.ts(a)  # ds[ ,4]
```

[image: plot of time series of a]

On the other hand, the method should not detect series data below as a step like shape although there is an increasing trend

```
b = c(4.0395, 4.0715, 3.9155, 4.065, 3.8804, 4.1018, 4.0128, 4.0536, 3.8843, 4.3133, 4.5442, 4.4616, 4.199, 4.1072, 4.9806, 5.0805, 5.285, 5.0236, 5.1037, 5.0898, 4.5565, 4.99, 5.0152, 5.2478, 5.2843, 5.2827, 5.3203, 5.3841, 5.8214, 5.7281)
> plot.ts(b)  # ds[ ,6]
```

[image: plot of time series of b]

Answer (score 1):

You could take derivative of this signal. Derivative of step should be one large spike, and derivative of second graph should have multiple small spikes.